# Why does pygame increase the image file size when drawing and saving on a surface?

Tags: python, image-processing, pygame

Lets say you have a surface "screen":

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
```

You can save a gray screen with:

```
screen.fill((100,100,100))   

pygame.image.save(screen,"image.png")
```

> Image size is around 2kb

If you now draw on the screen and save it again, the file size will increase:

```
screen.set_at((250,250),(50,50,50))
pygame.image.save(screen,"image2.png")
```

> Image size now is around 3kb

And it keeps increasing like that:

In this example its just a Langtons ant script, saving the screen every 30K steps.
The pictures are too similar in order to increase the file size like that. So I don't think the color values of the pixels are what makes such a difference in size.

[image: File Sizes]
[image: Image previews]

So why do the file sizes go up like that?

And how could you avoid that?

Comment: A PNG with one colored pixel will be pretty small in filesize. It looks like you're drawing multiple colored pixels on different points of the image, so each time it's getting more complex, thus increasing the amount of data needed to represent the image. The theoretical largest image would be one that's completely full of randomly colored pixels. If the resolution isn't increasing, then it has to be the contents of the image that are affecting its size. If you really want to be sure, try opening and exporting the images to PNG using another program and see what happens.

Comment: Also just try this with a drawing program. Paint one pixel on a gray background, then save it as a PNG. Then draw more pixels, and see how the file size is affected. It should be identical to the results you're seeing in pygame.

Comment: @RandomDavis Yea, seems to check out. Was really surprised, seeing such a small change quintuple the image size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like JPG, PNG compresses images to save space and transfer time, but in opposition to JPG, PNG is lossless, so it will have to be able to recreate the original image. A uniform grey surface is easy to compress, up to a very high degree (small file size). Random colored pixels added to the center of the image, are, by far, harder to compress and thus need more space to"describe" them. That's why your image size is growing. Image size would be a maximum if you completely filled your screen with random colored pixels. So the increase in size of your image file is nothing else than normal.